# Excel: how to skip a specific row in an array

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to skip a specific row in an array, not the value.

For instance, assume we're on the A column:

```
0
3
0 <--- Row 3
0
```

how can I skip the 3rd row in A1:A4, so small(A1:A4, 2) can equal to 0, and small(A1:A4, 3) would equal to 3.

I would like to skip a specific row, not the value. I cannot switch the rows, I require a formula that ignores a specific row in an array

Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: What are you doing with the values, are you going to sum them?

Comment: Depending on what you will do with those numbers will dictate how to ignore the third row.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to sum the numbers use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ROW(A1:A4)<>3)*(A1:A4))
```

If you are going to do anything else then most likely you will need an array entered formula with and IF inside:

```
IF(ROW(A1:A4)<>3,A1:A4)
```

This will make the formula an array formula that needs to confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

So for example if we wanted the MAX:

```
=MAX(IF(ROW(A1:A4)<>3,A1:A4))
```

Entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

For the Small:

```
=SMALL(IF(ROW(A1:A4)<>3,A1:A4),3)
```

Entered with Ctrl-Shift-Enter would return `3` not `0`

[image]

---

Another form of AGGREGATE that is the same as the small above:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,A1:A4/(ROW(A1:A4)<>3),3)
```

Comment: sorry this is not what i'm looking for, I'm asking a formula that skips or excludes a specific row. for instance, the array A1:A5, I wish to exclude A3, therefore I would only want to consider A1,A2, A4,A5

Comment: This does that. It skips row 3.

Comment: @user1121010 see edit for proof

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was looking for, how interesting the row function can be integrated with the if function, I did not visualize that outcome in my head lol, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is with the `INDEX` function creating an array of the rows you wish to retain (and there are many ways to create this array).  In your specific example, using `AGGREGATE` instead of `SMALL`:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,4,INDEX($A$1:$A$4,IF(1,N({1,2,4}))),2)
```

[image]

If you have just four rows and want to ignore just one, the approach doesn't really matter.  If your ranges are larger, and your selection of rows to ignore more complex (and more than just one), creating an array of row numbers to retain may be simpler.

Comment: Impressive formula, this one is capable of skipping more than 1 row by modifying the inputs of the N() function. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To skip the specified 3rd row in A1:A4

Try to enter this normal formula :

```
=SMALL(IF({1;1;0;1},A1:A4),3)
```

will return result `3`

and,

```
=SMALL(IF({1;1;0;1},A1:A4),2)
```

will return result `0`